# React- input field turns to string after onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state

I have a small app with three components

1. parent => `App`
2. Son => `Courses`
3. Grandchild => `Course`

The app state lies in the App component, in the Course component I have an input field with an onChange event that spouse to change the state in the app component, the problem is that every time I type the input changes to a string and I can't keep typing and changing the state.

The values arrive to the parent.

This is my Course code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Course extends Component {
    updatedGrade = (e) => {
        this.props.updateCourseGrade(Number(e.target.value), Number(e.target.id));

    };
    render() {
        const {id, courseType, courseName, courseGrade} = this.props.course;
        return (
            <tr key={id}>
                <td>
                    {courseName}
                </td>
                <td> 
                    {(courseType ? 'a' : 'm' )}
                </td>
                <td>
        {(courseGrade !== '' 
            ? courseGrade 
            : <input 
                type="number"
                id={id}
                onChange={this.updatedGrade}
                value={courseGrade}
            /> 
        )}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button 
                        onClick={this.props.removeCourse.bind(this, id)}
                        style={btnStyle}
                    >
                        remove
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

this is my App relevant code:

```
    class App extends Component {
  state = {
    courses: [
      {
        id: 1,
        courseName: 'bioliogy,
        courseType: false,
        courseHours: 10,
        courseGrade: ''
      },{
        id: 2,
        courseName: 'Mahematics,
        courseType: true,
        courseHours: 20,
        courseGrade: ''
      },{
        id: 3,
        courseName: 'History,
        courseType: false,
        courseHours: 30,
        courseGrade: 50
      }
    ]
  };



  updateCourseGrade(courseGrade, id){

    //const courseGradeNum = Number(courseGrade);
    this.setState({
      courses: this.state.courses.map(course => course.id === id ? {...course, courseGrade } : course)
    })
  console.log('courseGrade ', courseGrade);
```

Now, when I do this:

```
 updateCourseGrade(courseGrade, id){

    const courseGradeNum = Number(courseGrade);
    this.setState({
      courses: this.state.courses.map(course => course.id === id ? {...course, courseGradeNum } : course)
    })
```

The state will get a new value while typing named `courseGrade` and I don't want this.
as well the `courseGrade` is already defined as a `Number` in the `Course` component

What can I do? maybe I shouldn't use value in the `course` component?

**UPDATE**

According to Freeman Lambda request, this is the state after I change the value in the input field,
the state of `courseGrade` of the desired course changes. but because the input field disappears I cannot keep typing.

Link to a video that shows what happens
https://www.screencast.com/t/Cyz1v6zMWsq

Comment: try to use not `onChange` but `onInput` and use `e.currentTarget.value` instead of `e.target.value`

Comment: nope... still the same result

Comment: I could not clearly understand what is happening with your `updateCourseGrad` and what is it that you actually would want to happen there. Can you please extend the question with an example of `App`'s state before and after `updateCourseGrade` is executed?

Comment: I have extended my question, I want to be able to type more than one digit

Comment: I added a link to a video that show what happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
    {(courseGrade !== '' 
            ? courseGrade 
            : <input 
                type="number"
                id={id}
                onChange={this.updatedGrade}
                value={courseGrade}
            /> 
        )}
```

You explicitely change the input to a plain string a soon as `courseGrade` is `!== ''`

if you want to be able to keep typing you have to stick with an input during typing. If you want the input to disapear after typing you will have to add a button controlling a state that removes the input, for example:

```
class Course extends Component {
    state = {
        gradeValidated: false,
    }
    updatedGrade = (e) => {
        this.props.updateCourseGrade(Number(e.target.value), Number(e.target.id));

    };
    toggleGradeInput = (e) => {
        this.setState((state) => ({ gradeValidated: !state.gradeValidated }));

    };
    render() {
        const {id, courseType, courseName, courseGrade} = this.props.course;
        return (
            <tr key={id}>
                <td>
                    {courseName}
                </td>
                <td> 
                    {(courseType ? 'a' : 'm' )}
                </td>
                <td>
        {(this.state.gradeValidated 
            ? courseGrade 
            : <input 
                type="number"
                id={id}
                onChange={this.updatedGrade}
                value={courseGrade}
            /> 
        )}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button 
                        onClick={this.toggleGradeInput}
                        style={btnStyle}
                    >
                        toggle input
                    </button>
                    <button 
                        onClick={this.props.removeCourse.bind(this, id)}
                        style={btnStyle}
                    >
                        remove
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
courseGrade !== '' 
            ? courseGrade 
            : <input 
                type="number"
                id={id}
                onChange={this.updatedGrade}
                value={courseGrade}
            />
```

the first condition is set to true if you set any state instead of '', so my idea is to use a save button for the grate and onChange keep on a local state.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an updater function for this, I think what is happening is that state updates are getting batched.

So instead of

```
this.setState({
      courses: this.state.courses.map(course => course.id === id ? {...course, courseGradeNum } : course)
    })
```

try

```
this.setState( prevState => ({
      courses: prevState.courses.map(course => course.id === id ? {...course, courseGradeNum } : course)
    }))
```

If this wasn't the problem can you create a code sandbox because there just isn't enough code to understand what is going on. For example, updateCourseGrade is being bound anywhere.  don't know if you haven't or if you are just not showing it.

Comment: If the state updater function is new to you [http://joshpitzalis.com/setState](http://joshpitzalis.com/setState)